# Mimo 2G USB Monitor and cheap computer (Raspberry Pi?)

Tags: usb, embedded, monitors

I have a Mimo 2G USB Monitor (UM-710S I believe) which I got in college due to the lack of space for a real second monitor in the dorm.

Now I don't really have a use for it, so I thought of converting it into like a digital picture frame or something on a small/cheap Linux computer.

I was thinking that when more Raspberry Pi's come out, that might do the trick. I also have found that Linux drivers should work: http://libdlo.freedesktop.org/wiki/

So my question is, has anyone used this or a similar USB monitor with Linux? With ARM Linux (such as the Raspberry Pi)? 
And is the Raspberry Pi my best bet for a simple application like this? Or is there something else I should look into hardware-wise?

This is meant to be a relatively quick project to make use of something I already have. So I'm not looking for a completely custom hardware solution and it should be relatively cheap.

I hope this is the proper place to ask this, but it seemed like a valid question.

Comment: Did you have already take a look there: http://www.raspbmc.com/ and there: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Raspberry_Pi

Comment: Care about bandwidth!

While using same USB for disk, network and monitor could break your perfs!

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait, a RPi will be fine (I don't expect mine until late June, and I ordered a while ago). If you need it *NAO* then look into a plug computer.